# Replace strings containing only blanks with NA

Tags: r, na

I have a dataframe containing columns named Q1 through Q98. These columns contain strings (`"This is a string"`), yet some entries only contain a varying number of blanks (`" "`, `"    "`). I would like to replace all entries containing only blanks with `NA`.

Consider the dataframe created by the following code:

```
df<-data.frame(Q1=c("Test test","Test"," ","  "),Q2=c("Sample sample","    ","Sample","Sample"))
```

The solution would modify the above dataframe `df` such that `df$Q1[3:4]==NA` and `df$Q2[2]==NA`.

I have already tried using `grepl(" ", df)`, but this lets me replace every entry that *contains* blanks, not only those which *consist* purely of blanks.

Comment: @Dij Using your logic you can do `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, grep("[A-Za-z]+", x, invert = TRUE), NA))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate_all(~ ifelse(nchar(trimws(.)) == 0, NA_character_, .))

        Q1            Q2
1 Test test Sample sample
2      Test          <NA>
3      <NA>        Sample
4      <NA>        Sample
```

Or the same with `base R`:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(nchar(trimws(x)) == 0, NA_character_, x))
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 mutate_all(~ trimws(.)) %>%
 na_if(., "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for strings with a start `^`, then one or more spaces `+`, then an end `$`.

```
df[sapply(df, function(x) grepl('^ +$', x))] <- NA

#          Q1            Q2
# 1 Test test Sample sample
# 2      Test          <NA>
# 3      <NA>        Sample
# 4      <NA>        Sample
```

Some other possibilities

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) replace(x, grep('^ +$', x), NA))
#or 
replace(df, sapply(df, function(x) grepl('^ +$', x)), NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr`+`stringr` option

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate_all(~str_replace(., "^\\s+$", NA_character_))
#         Q1            Q2
#1 Test test Sample sample
#2      Test          <NA>
#3      <NA>        Sample
#4      <NA>        Sample
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply sub to all columns of whitespaces:

```
lapply(df, FUN = sub, pattern = "^\\s*$", replacement = NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R`

```
df[trimws(as.matrix(df)) == ''] <- NA
df
#        Q1            Q2
#1 Test test Sample sample
#2      Test          <NA>
#3      <NA>        Sample
#4      <NA>        Sample
```

---

Or with `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate_all(list(~ replace(., trimws(.)=="", NA)))
#        Q1            Q2
#1 Test test Sample sample
#2      Test          <NA>
#3      <NA>        Sample
#4      <NA>        Sample
```